# Show navbar on page load

Tags: html, angular-material, angular5

I want to show the side navigation bar initially when the page is loaded. Please help. I have written my entire code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hg33wo?file=app/sidenav-autosize-example.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the opened attribute as shown [here](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples)

```
<mat-drawer #drawer  opened="showFiller" class="example-sidenav" mode="side">
      <p>Auto-resizing sidenav</p>
</mat-drawer
```